# primeng p-multiSelect filter not working expect in angular

Tags: angular, search, filter, primeng

It uses the p-multiSelect component
If you search, the results and the list come out together..
Only no results found should come out, but the list doesn't seem to be filtered
How can I solve this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah8vM.png)

html

```
<p-multiSelect
   [options]="cities"
   [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"
   defaultLabel="Select a City"
   optionLabel="name">
</p-multiSelect>
```

ts

```
this.cities = [
   { name: "New York", code: "NY" },
   { name: "Rome", code: "RM" },
   { name: "London", code: "LDN" },
   { name: "Istanbul", code: "IST" },
   { name: "Paris", code: "PRS" }
];
```

``

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in StackBlitz? In [official docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/multiselect), it seems to work correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work even in StackBlitz...

Answer (score 0):

always take value in array of object in pair of label and value. Label is what we see and value is exact value that we bind.

<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code">

selectedCities1 = [{name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}]

in case of array of string no need to define label and value in p-multiselect